# Prompt box with 2 text fields

Tags: php, javascript

I am trying to make a social website.I need to create a `pop up window`(may be prompt box in javascript) when the user clicks on `create message` button.The pop up window should contain 2 text fields just like facebook message pop up window.First one for the name of the recipient and the second one for the message.I have searched a lot and could not get the correct one.

Comment: Have you tried (jquery dialog)[http://jqueryui.com/dialog/] ? This sounds like a simple case or perhaps I am missing something here.

Comment: This site is not about problems with searching. Please try to do somenthing on your own and come back when you are stuck with real problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the sample fiddle I 've made. Make the required adjustments and use it.

```
$("p").click(function () {
   $("<div class='popup'></div>").html('<input type="text" /><br /><input type="text" />').appendTo("body");
});​
```

Here is the sample fiddle of it.

http://jsfiddle.net/zsfE3/9/

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

There's no simple native method for creating a custom, multi-field input. [prompt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.prompt) offers an almost but not quite solution.

So, you would need to write script to produce this interface with the DOM. Libraries like [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com) offer generalised methods for creating elaborate UI components such as this.

Their dialog element's [modal form](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form) instance could help.

Answer (score 1):

You could implement a popup of your own and give it what ever functionality you desire. A good technique would be to place a div element at the very end of your pages `<body>` tag. Give it absolute positioning and the highest z-index you have and set display to none.

You place your popup contents in this element and whenever you want to display the popup you set the wrapper div to block display.

#### [Here is a quick demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gp54V/1/)

Comment: @ Lix Let me give a try.